# How to fill Tables ID column from another table using intermediate table as link

Tags: sql, join, sqlite, database-administration, insert-select

Redesigning a database layout and i've hit a road block:

The original table now named `Items_Old` had these 3 columns of importance:

```
Name | Width | Length
```

I have since made a new table called `ItemSizes`:

```
ID | Width | Length
```

and a last called `Items`:

```
Name | SizeID
```

I am trying to figure out how to select the SizeID from the `ItemSizes` table into `Items` Table

```
where Items_Old.Name = Items.Name and Items_Old.Width = ItemSizes.Width 
      AND Items_Old.Length = ItemSizes.Length
```

I have gotten as far as being able to get a list of SizeID and Items_Old.Name with the following:

```
Select IST.ID , Old.Name
From ItemSizes AS IST, Items_Old AS Old
Where IST.Width = Old.Width 
       And  IST.Length = Old.Length
```

but when I try something like :

```
Insert Into Items
(SizeID)
Select IST.ID , Old.Name
From ItemSizes AS IST, Items_Old AS Old
Where IST.Width = Old.Width 
       And  IST.Length = Old.Length
Where Items.Name = Info.Name
```

I get a syntax error because of the second Where I also tried

```
Insert Into Items
(SizeID)
(Select IST.ID , Old.Name
From ItemSizes AS IST, Items_Old AS Old
Where IST.Width = Old.Width 
       And  IST.Length = Old.Length) As Info 
Where Items.Name = Info.Name
```

but got an error `near "("`

Comment: I guess you already have some vales in the `Name` column of `Items` table and you want to *update* the `SizeID` column. Is it?

Comment: @BhupeshC Yes, I have come to realize that I don't want to insert and I do want to update, I have been trying to figure out the With syntax for an update now.

Comment: which is your database, Oracle, SQL Server, MySQL, etc. ?

Comment: @BhupeshC It is in the tags, and is `SQLite3`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In an UPDATE statement, you can look up values with a correlated subquery:

```
UPDATE Items
SET SizeID = (SELECT ID
              FROM ItemSizes
              JOIN Items_Old USING (Width, Length)
              WHERE Name = Items.Name)
```